# If in array and database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some issues with the following code. In my form *col6* and *col7* are not defined in every case.

```
 $data = Array (
    'col1' => time(),
    'col2' => $_SESSION['user'],
    'col3' => $_POST['incr'],
    'col4' => 0,
    'col6'=>$_POST['incit'],
    'col7'=>$_POST['incex']
    );


$db->where ('id', $_POST['incag']);
$id = $db->update ('table', $data);
```

How can I make my `$data`variable if `$_POST['incit']` is not set, to delete *col6* from array.

If column remains, the value in database is set to 0 or `null`. The value must be like `POST` in order not to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $data = [
    'col1' => time(),
    'col2' => $_SESSION['user'],
    'col3' => $_POST['incr'],
    'col4' => 0,
    'col7' => $_POST['incex'],
];
if (isset($_POST['incit'])) {
    $data['col6'] = $_POST['incit'];
}
```

One more thing - I hope that your $db layer is handling all SQL injection related things. As you are not doing any filtering, it can turn ugly very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `isset()`:

```
<?php 
$data = Array (
'col1' => time(),
'col2' => $_SESSION['user'],
'col3' => $_POST['incr'],
'col4' => 0,
'col7'=>$_POST['incex']
); 
if(isset($_POST['incit']) && !empty($_POST['incit'])) {
   $data['col6'] = $_POST['incit'];
}
?>
```

See more info about `isset()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).